# Setting up nodemailer for SMTP

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I used this setup to send a mail:

```
import NodeMailer from 'nodemailer'
import SmtpTransport from 'nodemailer-smtp-transport'

const transporter = NodeMailer.createTransport(SmtpTransport({
  host: 'smtp.1blu.de',
  port: 25,
  debug: true,
  auth: {
    user: '...',
    pass: '...'
  }
}))

transporter.sendMail(options, (error, data) => ...)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:25
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:749:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:772:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1009:14)
```

Seems like it ignores the host, but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the very same problem as you and I am using 1blu as well.
The issue is related to the TLS library of Node. The following configuration did the job for me.

## Here:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    host: 'smtp.1blu.de',
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 465,
    auth: {
       user: '...',
       pass: '...'
    },
    tls:{
        secureProtocol: "TLSv1_method"
    }
});
console.log('SMTP Configured');
```

Comment: After scouring the internet for several hours at a time for this, I've finally found what works with Firebase for non-gmail emails. Thank you